# VBA Excel pre-select items in a multicolumn multiselect listbox

Tags: excel, listbox, multi-select, userform, vba

I am trying to load a listbox with items with two columns, check each entry against a spreadsheet, and select the row if that entry is found.

The result is loading a customer list, identifying and selecting the items already on a mailing list, allowing the user to edit the selection and updating the spreadsheet with the updated selection.

I tried to do the check within the loading of the listbox, but since I was tripping with errors I separated it out to make things clearer, the error occurs in the code below on the line **CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1(j).Selected = True**

```
    With Rows(1)
        Set c = .Find(What:=showgroup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End With

    For i = 0 To wk.Sheets("temp").UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
        code = wk.Sheets("temp").Range("a" & mycount)
        company_name = wk.Sheets("temp").Range("b" & mycount)

        CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
        CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "40;80"
        CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1.AddItem
        CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1.list(i, 0) = code
        CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1.list(i, 1) = company_name
        mycount = mycount + 1
    Next


    For j = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        check = Me.ListBox1.list(j, 0)
        With Columns(c.Column)
            Set d = .Find(What:=check, MatchCase:=False)
        End With
        If Not d Is Nothing Then CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1(j).Selected = True
        If Not d Is Nothing Then Set d = Nothing
    Next
```

I've included the code for loading the listbox, as well as the loop to check each one against the spreadsheet, I've tried many combinations including:

```
CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1(j,0).Selected = True
CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1(j,1).Selected = True
CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1(j.row).Selected = True
```

...but all result in "Run-time error '424': Object required", I know I am not managing to work with the row here but searching the site and google I just find pages of information on how to read the selected items from a listbox and not much on how to select during initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
CRM_Edit_Groups.ListBox1.Selected(j) = True
```

Also, make sure that your list allows multiple selection. Select your listbox in userform window and go to object properties. There find property `MultiSelect` and chose option `1`.

Comment: Marius, that has done it, and better than that I can see where I was going wrong! Thank you